# What are the theories and methods of calculating the risk free value of lp tokens

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

I read from Olympus DAO discord that the risk free value of lp tokens can be calculated roughly by this formula: `sqrt(n_0*n_1)`, where `n_0`, and `n_1` are the numbers of the two tokens respectively. I'm wondering if this is true and what the exact formula and theory for this are. Thanks.

Comment: did you get an answer to your quesion? I'm also tryin to understand the ration al behind this formula...

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:

In he case of constant product AMMs like Uniswap v2, we've got: P(X)= k/x^2.
In the case of stablecoins, P(X) = P(Y) = 1 permanently (under the assumption that arbitrages are efficient).

Therefore we have:x^2=y^2=k, meaning x=y=sqrt(k). So x+y=2.sqrt(k)

Comment: Please explain each formula with more details and rationale. Thanks.

Comment: In Constant product AMM we have the bonding cuve: x.y=k. So y=k/x. The price of token Y in terms of X is y/x therefore Price= (k/x)/x=k/x^2.

Comment: In Constant product AMM we have the bonding cuve: x.y=k. So y=k/x. The price of token Y in terms of X is y/x therefore Price= (k/x)/x=k/x^2. In the case of OHM, its intrinsic value (from the protocol perspective) is 1USD. In order to estimate the value of the OHM-DAI Liquidity pool, you can say that the value of 1 OHM = value of 1 DAI and thus x=y in the above formulas. Thus we have: Value of the pool = 2x (in terms of X, in our case, in terms of OHM). And we have also x^2=k so x= sqrt(k). Therefore, the value of the pool = 2. sqrt(k).

Comment: Thanks, this is outstanding. A very clear explanation. Do you happen to know markdown as well? The markdown value of a lp bond.

Comment: I think what they mean with "mark down" is decreasing it's valuation down to its intrinsic value. Let say we speak about a OHM-DAI LP token. The intrinsic value of the DAI is 1 USD (or at least we consider it is the case). The value of the OHM can't be the OHm itself because it means nothing when valuating your assets in USD. So you have to go down to its backing in a worst case scenario (Treasury backing 1USD per OHM in average). The backing of the OHM is what they call "cyclical dependency"

Comment: Yes, this touched why marking down values is needed, however, marking down seems to be only applicable to a lp bond. I think I got it. The value of lp tokens are in risk free values, and the lp token bonds must be marked down values to be comparable to risk free values, otherwise, the bonds are sold at discount to OHM prices and lp tokens are calculated as risk free values. These two usually don't match, and the difference can be big, like $400 in (unmarked down) bond value and $20 in risk free value.